# webBrowser1 open webpage

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

How do I open the webpage in webBrowser1?

I added new webBrowser component into new window, when I added the button
this is the code on this button:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string URL = @"http://www.site.com/search?=N";
        this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(URL); 
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate("URL");
        this.webBrowser1.Refresh();

    }
```

But it does not work - no errors reported, but webBrowser1 does not show any data after the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("URL");
```

try:

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate(URL);
```

This way instead of navigating to the site `"URL"` (which obviously doesn't exist) you navigate to the site that the URL variable is pointing to (which is `http://www.site.com/search?=N`).

Answer (score 1):

Try not putting `URL` in quotes:

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate(URL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to:

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate(URL);
```